# Handlebars.js #each Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, trigger.io

I'm bashing my head against the desk on this one. I cannot understand why this isn't working.

I'm trying to use a simple handlebars #each loop to output stars with a css class defined in their model. I'm doing this on an iPhone in a UIWebView via Trigger.io (not sure if that's relevant or not). It simply does not output the variable into the template's HTML.

I've replicated the exact same code into a JS Fiddle and it works ( http://jsfiddle.net/yeldarb/c4GTc/1/ ) both on my computer and on my iPhone.

After checking and double checking the model, I finally decided to just output the variable without looping over it and that works fine.

The relevant part of the template then looked like this:

```
{{player_1.stars}}

<div class="player_1">
    <div class="stars">
        {{#each player_1.stars}}
            <div class="star {{this}}"></div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
```

Which confirmed what I suspected: Handlebars is getting the data from the model but the #each loop is somehow failing.

[image: Result of the above code]

See how it outputted starred,starred,starred for {{player_1.stars}}? Well, the resulting HTML looks like this:

[image: Resulting html]

Craziness I tell you. Those `<div class="star "></div>` lines should have been `<div class="star starred"></div>`

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I've seen a similar question posted a lot of times here and they all come down to using <% around the eaches.

Comment: Can you link me to one of those? What does <% do? Don't see that in the docs

Comment: Are you sure `stars` is an array?

Comment: Yep, I even tried hardcoding it in the model just before running the model through the template as ['starred', 'starred', 'unstarred'] with the same result.

Comment: I went back to handlebars RC1 and now at least I get an error and they fail to render: "error occurred: src/libraries/handlebars/handlebars-1.0.0rc1.js:1726: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Comment: What the heck? If I have the Safari Remote Web Inspector open it works (very consistently). Makes it hard to debug! What would having the web inspector open change that would affect this?

Comment: I was able to enable debug mode on Handlebars leading up to the exception but I don't know how to read this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=u9zYFZHL

Comment: I give up. Here's the debug output from 1.0.10 if anyone has any interest. I've convinced myself this is a bug in handlebars: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uV7daUd2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug present in an earlier version of Handlebars which has now been fixed.